# failed to run xterm in fluxion

Tags: linux, networking, terminal, xterm

so i cloned the fluxion repository from github and when i tried to run the tool (as root) it showed me this error

```
[*] Failed to start xterm session (possible misconfiguration).
```

then i closed that terminal and typed xterm in another terminal. but when i run it a root it says

```
root@localhost:~# xterm
No protocol specified
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s
```

after that i changed xhost to local but same result

please someone help me with this and thanks!

Comment: Not a programming problem - try [su] or [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

That’s because ur internet is not work or upgrade ur machine or install xterm

Answer (score 0):

It means you need to exit root

```
root@yourpc:~$exit
```

and don't run with sudo either.

It's saying it doesn't need nor will it run with elevated (root) permission/access.

That solves the issue you see.